# Compare Multiple Variable (or String) to List

Tags: python, list, logical-operators

I'm trying to make a logical that will compare multiple string to a list, for example:

```
myList=['str1','str2','str3']
if 'str1' in myList and 'str5' in myList and 'str10' in mylist:
    print('all three')
elif 'str1' in myList or 'str5' in myList or 'str10' in mylist:
    print('any')
```

Is there any simple way to do that (not repeating the in myList or any simple way for many input)? The correct answer for above example is 'any'.

The logical should be able to handle 'or' and 'and'.
*I've already browse this topic around and can't find the answer I'm looiking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists `any` and `all`

```
compare_list = ['str1', 'str5', 'str10']
print(any(i in compare_list for i in myList))
print(all(i in compare_list for i in myList))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set instead of list. Then use `issubset` function for subset, and length of the `difference` to check if any common value between the two exists.

```
mySet={'str1','str2','str3'}
if {'str1' , 'str5', 'str10'}.issubset(mySet):
    print('all three')
elif len({'str1' , 'str5', 'str10'}.difference(mySet))>0:
    print('all three')
```

Comment: Check your print strings.

Comment: This one is gold, i need to edit it a bit for my actual case but thank you very much!

My edit:

elif len(checkSet.difference(mySet))>0 and len(checkSet.difference(mySet))<len(checkSet):
    print('any')
else:
    print('none')

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new list of all the items you want to check and go through the new list:

```
myList=['str1','str2','str3']
new_checks=['str2', 'str4']
for i in new_checks:
   if i in myList:
      print(i)
```

You can also save results to a new list and if its not empty print whatever you need:

```
myList=['str1','str2','str3']
new_checks=['str2', 'str4']
in_first_list=[]   
for i in new_checks:
   if i in myList:
      in_first_list.append(i)
print(in_first_list)
```

or just the length of the items .. len(in_first_list)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `any` and `all` functions that python has. Together with a list comprehension, the solution looks like this:

```
myList=['str1','str2','str3']
if all([s in myList for s in ['str1', 'str5', 'str10']]):
    print('all three')
elif any([s in myList for s in ['str1', 'str5', 'str10']]):
    print('any')
```

You can provide the list of strings to be checked as any iterable.